# How would one spell θæn?

Tags: transliteration

My four-year-old recently got a pet frog. When he named it, he said, "θæn" (note: that is IPA, "θæn" sounds just like the word "than" but it has an unvoiced first consonant). I'm not sure how to notate this into English though. My wife suggested we just go with "Than", but to me, that's the common, "ðæn". I was thinking perhaps "Thann", but that looks like it should be "θɑn". Is there already a word which is pronounced θæn? If not, what would an English spelling look like?

Comment: How does <Thann> look like it should be pronounced /θɑːn/? That would definitely be /θæn/ for me (of course, I'm English).

Comment: I agree.  Double the final consonant to devoice the initial consonant. Isn't English spelling funn?

Comment: In English I have heard the word "then" pronounced with just about every vowel sound imaginable. "Than" has a bit less variation, but its still not as standard as you make out.

Comment: ***Thy thigh is thicker than this thistle***. That pronunciation exercise might help learners appreciate the fact that there are two different phonemes involved, but the orthography itself doesn't seem to offer any clues as to which is which.

Comment: @Nothingatall Probably because I'm an American who's studied German. German words with the "ann" structure are `ɑn`.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is there a rule there? Or is that something you've just observed?

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm inclined to agree with you, but I'd love to know *WHY*.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Doesn't German have a centralized or front /a/?

Comment: The closest word I can find to this pronunciation is the name [Thanatos](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thanatos), which has a first syllable pronounced `θæn` and only uses one n.

Comment: Inspired by Ha'ant http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hant  pronunced  hænt maybe you could use "Th'an" ?  Or else there's at least a word where than is pronunced θæn : thanathos (god of death) -->ˈθænəˌtɒs     There's a comic's character call Thanos derived from this, probalby where your son got it from.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Perhaps you could transliterate it as people have encyclopædia - with a long e sound: Theen.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Lawler was making a joke about the state of English spelling. 'Thann' makes sense as a spelling because it follows a rule of not following rules.

Comment: It's not a dead-on match, but I would suggest the English word *thane*.

Comment: Throwing my hat into the ring: go with Thanne. Rhymes with Anne!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

**thanh**

It is one of the very common names in Vietnam. Usually for a girl. Actual meaning in Vietnamese: Blue, pure.  [from here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thanh)

Comment: Wrong direction. I know how it's pronounced, but eventually, he'll want me to write the fool thing's name down.

Comment: Or:  **thanh**
   It is one of the very common names in Vietnam. Usually for a girl. Actual meaning in Vietnamese: Blue, pure.  [from here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thanh)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev You can edit your answer with "thanh". Looks better.

Comment: I would pronounce "Thanh" in English with /t/, not with /θ/.

Comment: I've found it by googling for the requested pronunciation. The thing is - it's not English, it's Vietnamese.. Try to google it.

Comment: As a point of irony: the damn thing died within a month of this stupid post.